# COUNT(*) with and without GROUP BY, no matching rows

Tags: mysql, sql

Consider a relation table (Balance,Customer) with the following records:

[image: screenshot of database table]

Now I tried [these two queries here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ef41b/1):

```
-- Query 1:
select A.Customer, count(B.Customer)
from account A, account B
where A.balance < B.balance
group by A.Customer;

-- Query 2:
select A.Customer, count(B.Customer)
from account A, account B
where A.balance < B.balance;
```

The first query gives me no output. With the second query, I am getting an output with count = 0.

In both cases there are no rows satisfying the criteria in the `where` clause, and hence no rows are returned. Then why is the `count` function giving an output only in the second case?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  The second is not valid SQL, although one or two databases accept it.

Comment: Hi, the SQL returns no data because you have no data that satisfy the condition where A.balance<B.balance. The sample data suggests that all balances are 200, right?

Comment: I have included sql fiddle link in case anyone needs to try it.

Comment: @Zephyr ptovide data returned to help you more

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An aggregation query that has no `group by` *always* returns one row (if it is syntactically correct).  The count in such a row would be `0`.

An aggregation query with a `group by` returns one row per group.  If there are no groups then there are no rows.

Comment: Is it the case only with group by or are there any other clauses where this happens? Also, if it always returns one row then why is count value 0, shouldn't it be 1?

Comment: There are 0 rows that match your condition, why would you expect a count of 1? (And what are you trying to achieve with your query?)

Comment: Yes, you get one row, and the `count(B.consumer)` value in that row is zero. But you really should not use that second query.

Comment: @Zephyr As the answerer said in a comment to your question & as others have said, your use of the second query (which is not standard SQL because it selects non-aggregated columns that are not functionally dependent on the (implicit) grouped column set) suggests that you don't understand querying with aggregates. It's too bad this answer doesn't explain about this. (But then, this is a faq.)

Answer (score 0):

the SQL returns no data because you have no data that satisfy the condition where A.balance

Comment: But why is it returning the data in second case ?