# CodeIgniter count within query as extra column

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

I am having a query in CodeIgniter which is working fine. 
Now I would like to have an additional COUNT inside per output line, this data is shown inside a table.
I want to see per line how much times the user has requested a device.

I don't want the output to be grouped, I want one column per row that says this user has 3 requests, so in this case 3 rows from the same user, having a different deviceRequest, with 3 times in this column count being 3.

PS: I am quite new to this, info about your solution would be appreciated.

Query:

```
$datatables->select('
                deviceRequestID,
                deviceRequestStatuses.deviceRequestStatusShortname,
                users.userEmail,
                users.userID,
                users.userName,
                users.userSurname,
                deviceRequestComments,
                deviceRequests.createdAt,
                deviceRequests.updatedAt,
                rooms.roomName,
                hotspots.hotspotName,
                hotspots.hotspotAddress,
                hotspots.hotspotCity,
                hotspots.hotspotZIP,
                DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), deviceRequests.createdAt) AS daysDifference,
        ')
            ->join('users', 'deviceRequests.userID=users.userID', 'left')
            ->join('deviceRequestStatuses', 'deviceRequests.deviceRequestStatusID=deviceRequestStatuses.deviceRequestStatusID')
            ->join('rooms', 'users.roomID=rooms.roomID', 'left')
            ->join('hotspots', 'rooms.hotspotID=hotspots.hotspotID', 'left')
            ->from('deviceRequests');
```

Comment: use group by to get the count

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46308005/count-with-and-without-group-by-no-matching-rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added this extra query line inside the select part of the query above, it does exactly what I need.

```
(SELECT count(userID) FROM deviceRequests WHERE userID = users.userID) AS deviceCount
```